# How to save games in ChessBase reader?

Tags: pgn, database, chessbase

I played a very interesting game today, and I entered it in ChessBase reader, along with some comments. I would love to save this game in a database (.cbh) or as a .pgn, but I don't know how. Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you try to create your own database on ChessBase and insert your game in it? I do this to save my games and it works well.

Comment: I used the board setting.

Comment: You can only do it with ChessBase but can't with ChessBase reader.

Answer (score 4):

I found an easy way to save pgns in CBReader. File->Publish to WEB->One-click publication-> the browser will open with your game and 'Download PGN' option. Really fast and easy.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, in fact in "Chessbase reader", there is the word **reader** which means you can only pgn (or .cbh ...)

If you want to do such thing, my advice is for you to get a copy of the most used software like Chessbase or Fritz.
Probably there is some free stuff which are doing the same but I don't know it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do this in chessbase reader. You can use Arena Chess (free) to do this then transfer this .pgn into Chessbase Reader. Reader allows me to use Chessbase products for training but to evaluate my own games I use Arena.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [ChessDB](http://chessdb.sourceforge.net/) which claims to be the best free chess database program out there, although that was in 2007 ;-). It is quite powerful for a free program with the ability to download from TWIC from within the program. Also import from a player's ICC history. You can hook up to UCI interface games engines.

Of course you can save your games into a database but you cannot import Chessbase format. It has good search capabilities for a free program like player reports and search for games with exact position match.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot save new games with chessbase reader, you can edit and replace existing ones. So what I do is open a .pgn file (I created one and copy and rename it for each tournament) full of empty games and edit these, i.e. double click an empty game, enter the moves and comments, then right click the game in the list and select replace which lets you edit the metadata and writes the game to the .pgn file. 
Only the site tag seems to be unavailable, but if you edit it manually, cb reader will display it if the tournament name is short enough.

Answer (score 0):

another simple way is to copy and past your game to a text file and save it as a .pgn , later on you can open it on any chess software.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, or add anything new that isn't in the other answers.

Comment: have you ever used notepad to save a chess game and past it to a software later?